# I need to place the logo over the textfiled like mention below image in flutter

Tags: flutter

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bFDF.png)

I've endeavored to replicate the design mentioned earlier but faced challenges. Unfortunately, I couldn't achieve the desired outcome. I kindly request assistance in comprehending and executing the process accurately. Your guidance would be immensely appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(21, 128, 197, 1),
          title: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 70, // Adjusted width to accommodate CircleAvatar
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 25,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: ClipOval(
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/logo_1.png",
                        height: 45,
                        width: 45,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    ),
                    child: const TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search...',
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

I am attempting to replicate the design shown above to meet my requirements but have been unable to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above image like this below code:

You have to wrap your entire widget into the stack and put image on top of the text field and align them to center left,

So you can achieve your desired UI Also adjust your text field's content padding for proper text showing.

```
Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        children: [
          Row( // Your TextField Widget
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  height: 30,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                  child: const TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Search...',
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 80.0, right: 10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Container( // Your Image Widget
            width: 70, // Adjusted width to accommodate CircleAvatar
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 25,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```